# Simple_html_dom get image url inside data-src

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How do i get the **image url** inside **data-src**?

```
<img src="http://example.com/lightbox-blank.gif" data-src="http://example.com/img/2f8556.1.jpg" id="pic1545" /></a>
```

i try this and get error "*Use of undefined constant src - assumed 'src'*" with no result

```
$html->find('div.thumb img',$i)->data-src;
```

Help please
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried is almost right, except for the part which you are using `data-src` as an attribute name. For such attribute names (i.e. including special chars) you can use `->{'attribute-name'}` syntax:

```
$html = str_get_html('<img src="http://example.com/lightbox-blank.gif" data-src="http://example.com/img/2f8556.1.jpg" id="pic1545" />');

print $html->find("img", 0)->{'data-src'};
```